# Jquery shorthand IF-ELSE

Tags: jquery, css, html, shorthand

i need to do a shorthand IF-ELSE with JQuery. 
My code:

```
    $('#somediv').val() != 0 ? $('#somediv').toggleClass('class1') : $('#somediv').toggleClass('class2');
```

Simple code, but doesn't work. Some help please?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
this work:

```
if ($('#somediv').val() != 0) {
    $('#somediv').toggleClass('class1');
}else{
    $('#somediv').toggleClass('class2');
}
```

But the shorthand doesn't...Ty for the patience

Comment: You want to check if #somediv content is empty and do something accordingly?

Comment: Just FYI, the if/else "shorthand" you are trying to use is called the `ternary` operator and is not something jQuery provides.  It is part of the basic Javascript syntax.

Comment: The div contains a variable that can hold only 1 or 0 monitored real time

Answer (score 3):

If `somediv` is actually a div as the name would indicates, you should use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `val()` since value is only valid for input elements.

Comment: The div contains a variable that can hold only 1 or 0 monitored real time, i've tried text() and html() but doesn't work...

Comment: As Claudio pointed out, `val()` doesn't work on a `div`, only on `input` fields.  See an example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3D6bn/)

Comment: @SimoneMelloni: could you check this jsfiddler to see if this is what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/7psC6/

Comment: First of all, the code you posted above DOES work.  You can see it in this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/3D6bn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/3D6bn/1/).  However, it does NOT WORK as you expect it to work. You will ALWAYS toggle `class2` only, because `$('#somediv').val()` will ALWAYS be '' (empty string) - for the reason Claudio explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use text() to get the value of the div, that's if it's not an input. If you provide what `#somediv` looks like that will help.

```
 $('#somediv').text() != 0 ? $('#somediv').toggleClass('class1') : $('#somediv').toggleClass('class2');
```

The shorthand "if-else" is called [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and can be used with vanilla javascript